# Python SIFT Descriptor reduction using PCA

Tags: python, pca, sift

I have a descriptors of an image that I generate using SIFT method in PYTHON, and I want to reduce the dimension using PCA, but i confused how to do that. there are some example but it using matlab.
can someone help me to solve that using python, or have some reference that I can read ?

from the data i get the descriptor of the image

thank you.

```
def pickle_keypoints(keypoints, descriptor, name):
i = 0
temp_array = []
for point in keypoints:
    temp = (point.pt, point.size, point.angle, point.response, point.octave,
    point.class_id)    
    temp_array.append(temp)  
keypoints_desc_name = (temp_array,descriptor,name) 
return keypoints_desc_name

surf = cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF_create()

for (x, y, w, h) in data:
    crop_face = image[y:y+h,x:x+w] ## y dan x sengaja dibalik
    kp, des = surf.detectAndCompute(crop_face, None)
    print('len(keypoints)', len(kp))
    temp = pickle_keypoints(kp, des, name)
    SURF_keypoints_descriptors_names.append(temp)
```

Comment: Hi Rifqi, Welcome to SO, it would be helpful if you can post some snippets of code, so that we can understand better, what is the actual question and what u have accomplished so far.

Comment: done, i posted it, thank you